# Which neighbourhood in Prague should one stay in to be close to the nightlife and the main sights?

Tags: sightseeing, walking, nightlife, prague

Prague is well known for having a very active night life with clubs, bars and old pubs.  My friends and I are going there for 4 nights and would like to stay in a neighbourhood that is close to the bars/pubs so we can walk home at night but also not too far from the main sights of the inner city.

Is this even viable or should we focus on one or the other and accept that we'll have to take some buses every day?

PS
We are all avid hikers and love to go around on foot as much as possible, that being said we will obviously do a day trip or two in or around the city.

Comment: Why the close votes? The location of the majority of clubs, bar and pubs is surley an objective matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prague 1** has both the biggest concentration of bars, clubs and old pubs, and the biggest concentration of sights. Check out the Foursquare map for the [top-rated sights](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Prague%2C%20Czech%20Republic&nearGeoId=72057594040995632&q=Popular%20with%20Visitors):

[image]

And the [top-rated night venues](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Prague%2C%20Czech%20Republic&nearGeoId=72057594040995632&q=Nightlife):

[image]

Therefore you should stay in **Prague 1**. I can recommend staying near the [intersection of Vodickova street and Wencelas square](https://goo.gl/maps/qSmJLGrmyns), as that's the nexus of Prague's public transport.